# Problem from complex analysis regarding series representation

Tags: laurent-series

The question asks

Represent the function $f(z) = \frac{z+1}{z-1}$ by its Maclaurin series for $|z|<1$ and its Laurent series for $1<|z|<\infty$.

The answers the book gives are:

Maclaurin series: $-1-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}z^n$

Laurent series: $1+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{z^n}$

The answers I got were:

Maclaurin series: $-(z+1)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n$

Laurent series: $\frac{z+1}{z}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{z^n}$, for the same intervals.

Where do the $1$ and $2$ constant/coefficient come from? Are my answers correct but just not in the given form? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**.  Your answer for the Maclaurin series can be expanded:
$$\eqalign{-(z+1)\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n
  &=-(z+1)(1+z+z^2+\cdots)\cr
  &=-z-1-z^2-z-z^3-z^2-\cdots\ .\cr}$$
As you can see, there is often more than one $z$ term with the same exponent.  If you collect terms you will get the simplified series.

Comment: Dang, so my answer was correct and just not in the form of the answer? I spent too much time on this haha.

Comment: Debatable whether or not your answer was correct.  It was "algebraically correct" but it was not exactly a power series.  If it was an exam and I was marking it I would give part marks, but not full marks.